# Why is the DataGridViewRow.Cells[1].Value returns null while it is not null?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Consider this very simple testproject :

DataGridView1 has 2 columns, both are set in designtime by right-mouse/edit columns.
In the ctor DataGridView1 is populated with 11 records
When running the application the 11 records are showing in DataGridView1

Now for the problem.
When you click on the button, the method CreateResultDataTable() is called and it throws a null reference exception on

```
row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()
```

the Value appears to be null while I know it is not.

Now for the strange part, when debugging and I move the mouse over row I see it has 2 cells. So I move the mouse over it and open the cells enumeration, than open the second cell and indeed the value is null.
So now I move the mouse over dataGridView1.Rows and move the mouse over the first of the 11 rows, than again over the cells and open the enumeration, and when I go into the second cell than the value is NOT NULL !
Are they not the same object ?

How can this be ? and how to get around this ?

I tried using the name of the column in stead of the index but the result stays the same, I still get the nulreference exception.

here is the complete code of the program:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadMapping();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = CreateResultDataTable();
    }

    private DataTable CreateResultDataTable()
    {
        DataTable Result = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            Result.Columns.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()); // why is Value null here ??
        }
        return Result;
    }

    private void LoadMapping()
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Header//Message_Type", "MessageType");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Header//Creation_Date", "MessageDate");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Header//Sequence_Number", "MessageSequenceNumber");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Header//Sender", "MessageSender");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Header//Receiver", "MessageReceiver");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Detail//Visit//Transport_Reference_Out", "LotNumber");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Detail//Visit//Licenseplate", "TruckPlate");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Detail//Visit//Cargo//VIN", "ChassisNumber");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Detail//Visit//Cargo//Make", "BrandName");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Message//Detail//Visit//Cargo//LoadDate", "LaadDatum");
    }
}
```

Comment: @GuidoG I took the comment out as I realised I was incorrect! Have you tried skipping the first row?

Comment: @stuartd How can I check in my loop if it is a header row or not ?

Comment: @stuartd Looks like you where right after all, see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add this code to deal with the header row. You have to check that a cell has a value (i.e. is not null) before you use `Tostring()`; if the cell is null then `ToString()` will throw an exception.

```
  private DataTable CreateResultDataTable()
  {
        DataTable Result = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            var cell = row.Cells[1].Value;
            if (cell != null) {
                Result.Columns.Add(cell.ToString()); // Why is Value null here??
            }
        }
        return Result;
  }
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain a bit why I need to do it like this ?

Comment: `null` means cell value wasn't touched yet. `string.Empty` means cell value is set, but is empty i.e `""`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private DataTable CreateResultDataTable()
  {
        DataTable Result = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
           
                Result.Columns.Add(row.Cells[1].Value?.ToString()); 
        }
        return Result;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).