# Why is the DataGridViewRow.Cells[x].Value returns null while it is not null?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, datagridviewrow

I know it seems a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144567/why-is-the-datagridviewrow-cells1-value-returns-null-while-it-is-not-null), but I have something different to ask. I am working on a simple winforms project which connects with a local database file which has two tables. I am showing data from those tables in two different datagridviews in two forms. Also I am changing colors of the rows of datagridview to differentiate male and female.

on one form the below code works and change color of the row.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString().Contains("Female"))
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;                                
        }
```

Output :
[image]

but on the other form the code is,

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Contains("Female"))
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
            
        }
```

(that table has extra column so Gender goes to the sixth one)

this gives me an error like this.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.
```

I know that the second table has data and not null.
Please can you tell me why the same code does not run on another form?

**Update**

I checked the data coming from the table by commenting out the error code and adding the line below,

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
```

it shows the messagebox with values I expected.

output: [image]

Comment: Check the data in ```Cells``` to see is that what you need

Comment: @MichaelMao updated the question with data in the exact cell and it is what I wanted. Please check the update

Comment: I think there are some values of cell are NULL in your table

Comment: @MichaelMao thanks, please how can I solve that? I can add a null check as in the question I mentioned at the beginning, but I want to understand what is going on here..

Comment: Do you have a data entry row at the bottom of the grid? If so, every cell in that row contains null. That is not the same as a database null, which is a DBNull object.

Comment: I don't know what happen. It's all my guess

Comment: @jmcilhinney  You are absolutely correct, that's the difference I did not notice yet. Thanks a lot, how can I get rid of that? or I will google that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney fixed it and now no errors. Thanks a lot. You can add it as an answer if you wish

Comment: @NuwanThisara Could you mark my answer if it solved your problem? This will help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As jmcilhinney said, null here is not database null.

You just need to turn off the allow editing of the table and it will work normally.

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Comment: You of course don't do that if you allow users to add data. You just loop the rows excluding the last (with a `for` loop, usually) -- BUT, you don't loop the Rows to change the color of Cells based on conditions, you use the `CellFormatting` event instead. Hence, no loops and no such mistakes. Still need to check for `null` / `DbNull.Value` (but this you do all the time, so...)

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I like the above mentioned solution. but If you want a editable grid you can try following condition as well `if(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value == null) return;`